# Pandas read_csv dtype convets column incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following CSV

```
"1"
"2"
"23"
```

and I read it

```
names = ["nullable"]
dtype = [("nullable", 'int32')]
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\work\nullable.csv",
                 names=names,
                 dtype=dtype,
                 encoding = "utf-8")
```

Looking at `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
nullable    3 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(1)
memory usage: 140.0 bytes
None
```

If I add a `""` (a `NaN`) to the CSV and change the `dtype` to `pd.Int32Dtype` the `df.info()` shows object type.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 1 columns):
nullable    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 160.0+ bytes
None
```

However if I do

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2.0, np.nan, 4.0])

s2 = s.astype('Int32')
```

The `dtype` is correctly filled in as `Int32`

```
s2.info()
AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute 'info'")
s2
0      1
1      2
2    NaN
3      4
dtype: Int32
```

This looks like a bug to me.

Are there any suggestions on how to work around this? Since I want to save the CSV as parquet, but if I use `pd.Int32Dtype` the column is saved as a string.

It's not feasible to remove or replace `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas read_csv interprets 'NaN' as Null but not 'NAN'.  You can pass 'NAN' to the na_values argument.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\work\nullable.csv",
                 names=names,
                 dtype=dtype,
                 encoding = "utf-8",
                 na_values = 'NAN'
            )
```

Comment: Sorry, expression on NAN must have confused you. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm running '0.25.0' and using pd.Int32Dtype works as expected.  Maybe your version has an issue?